# FactoryBot create function takes a really long time

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I work in a codebase that makes extensive use of FactoryBot to create test objects.  I recently timed how long it took to create some instances of our most commonly-used class, and found that it's on the order of 0.2 seconds apiece.  Some of my tests create around 100 objects, so that's a substantial time sink.

Why might object creation be taking so long?  Does FactoryBot offer any way to break down the time it spends?

Comment: Do you have one factory calling another factory, and so on? Fixtures are faster, but they will probably take a lot of work to replace your factories

Comment: Heavy factory cascades and heavy validations / callbacks are usually the pain point. To be really sure, you might want to profile your tests, see [this article](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/testprof-a-good-doctor-for-slow-ruby-tests).